# Object-oriented representation of date and time in C++

Tags: c++, linux, time, gettimeofday

I am writing C++ code for an embedded Linux system. Traditionally, on Linux, the date and time would be retrieved by calling the library function `gettimeofday()`. But that doesn't feel very object-oriented to me. I would like to instead be able to write code similar to this:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime;
DateTime duration = new DateTime(2300, DateTime.MILLISECONDS)
DateTime deadline = now + duration;

while(now < deadline){
    DoSomething();
    delete now;
    now = new DateTime()
}
```

where there is a `DateTime` class, which can be constructed with the current time or a particular time, and which offers member functions or even overloaded operators to perform operations on the represented date and time.

Is there something like this offered by the C++ standard libraries? I cannot use the Boost libraries on my target system. However, I could consider porting something simple (something implemented with header files only, for example).

Comment: Well, Boost.Date_Time should be easy to port. Also, you really shouldn't be allocating local objects with `new`, especially on an embedded system.

Comment: [Date and time utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So porting boost wasn't an option for my target.  Instead I had to go with gettimeofday().  There are however some nice macros for dealing with timeval structs in `sys/time.h`

```
#include <sys/time.h>

void timeradd(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b,
          struct timeval *res);

void timersub(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b,
          struct timeval *res);

void timerclear(struct timeval *tvp);

void timerisset(struct timeval *tvp);

void timercmp(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b, CMP);
```

It took a while to find them though because they weren't in the man pages on my machine.  See this page:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/timercmp

Answer (score 6):

There is no object-oriented interface for dealing with time and intervals that's part of the standard C++ library.

You might want to look at [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time.html) though.  [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is so useful and well written that its practically a part of the standard C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be fine with using stuff from ctime

```
#include <ctime>

time
difftime
mktime
```

should do the job in a very portable way.
[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/)

Comment: I looked at this but the resolution is too coarse.  I want to get down to millisecond resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/include/linux/time.h
```

gives structure :-

```
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

on Linux, may be you could use it...